# Signalling error from the callback of a subcommand in CLI11

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm using CLI11 and I've defined a subcommand with a callback.

`https://cliutils.gitlab.io/CLI11Tutorial/chapters/subcommands.html`

How do I signal if an application error happens? I would like my program to return non-zero exit code in some cases and possibly do some processing too. Is there a documentated way? I don't like using internal things like ParseError or Error unless it is documented how to use it.

Ways I see (that does not use undocumented CLI11 features):

- Assign a global variable from callback lambda. Check this after calling CLI11_PARSE.
- Throw an exception in callback lambda. Catch it in main when calling CLI11_PARSE.